# Контекстно( )зависимый: как всё-таки правильно?

Tags: орфография

Занимаюсь локализацией различных аппаратных и программных продуктов и руководств к ним. И всякий раз, как встречаю *context sensitive* или подобный оборот, впадаю в задумчивость: как же всё-таки правильно писать «контекстно зависимый»?
С одной стороны, «контекстно» — это просто наречие, соответственно, это два разных слова. Этот же вариант даёт и единственный словарь на [Грамоте.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x).
С другой стороны, это слово воспринимается (чисто интуитивно?) как прилагательное с соединительной гласной (хотя тогда должно же быть «контекстозависимый», откуда суффикс *н*?) и писаться, соответственно, слитно (ибо не «контекстный и зависимый», а «зависящий от контекста», согласно школьному правилу написания таких слов через дефис).
Однако я много где, включая и авторитетные источники, встречаю написание через дефис, что вызывает у меня несколько противоречивые чувства.
Как вы, думаю, можете заметить, в целом проблем с грамотностью у меня нет, и поэтому когда не знаешь, как написать или произнести какое-либо слово, это вызывает дискомфорт, сходный с тем, какой вызывает у сэра Шурфа Лонли-Локли любая неточность в высказывании собеседника (кто читал, поймёт).
Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно, желательно с доказательством.

Comment: Можно ещё говорить "зависящий от контекста". Хотя я понимаю, что вы хотите понять, как правильно именно в вашей формулировке. Я сам затрудняюсь сказать.

Comment: Вот здесь http://www.wikiznanie.ru/wikipedia/index.php/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81,_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5 есть более подробно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

«Контекстно зависимый», "контекстно обусловленный", "контекстуально зависимый" - это всё сочетания наречия на -о и причастия или прилагательного. О том, что это наречие, говорит вопрос к нему: зависимый как? в каком отношении?-контекстно, контекстуально. Контекстно = от контекста, в контексте.

Вообще, если к словам, связанным по принципу примыкания, можно поставить разные вопросы - это отдельные слова.

Вот контекстно-ситуативный - контекстный и ситуативный, поэтому через дефис, сочинительная связь.

Контактоустанавливающий = устанавливающий что? контакт-подчинительная связь управление - слитно.

Comment: Людмила, а почему тогда "громкоговорящий", "глубокоуважаемый" пишутся слитно?

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! И да, присоединяюсь к вопросу Артёма :)

Comment: В профильной литературе "контекстно-зависимая грамматика" уже много лет, и нигде не видел варианта "контекстно зависимая грамматика". И со многими подобными терминами из ИТ ситуация та же. Так что тут не всё так гладко.

Comment: Aртем, такие написания подпадают под правила подчинительного написания слов.  Пишутся слитно сложные имена прилагательные, образованные из сочетаний слов, по своему значению подчиненных одно другому. Сюда же относятся обозначающие единое понятие образования (в том числе и терминологические) из наречия и прилагательного (или причастия), например:глубокоуважаемый, малоупотребительный,сильнодействующий. См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Д. Э. Розенталь. Академический справочник.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Серж, за объяснения!

Comment: Глубокоуважаемый, вышеуказанный, вечнозелёный, быстрорастворимый, сильнодействующий, легковоспламеняющийся - явные термины. Здесь разночтений нет. Кроме того, глубокоуважаемый может употребляться в роли существительного(субстантивир. прилагат.) Лопатин приводит примечание:
Пишутся слитно прилагательные, преимущественно употребляющиеся в функции имен существительных, напр.: военнопленный, военнообязанный, срочнослужащий, ссыльнокаторжный, ссыльнополитический, земноводные, парнокопытные.

Comment: Можно посмотреть у Лопатина http://www.orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1357  Громкоговорящий относится к орфографич. трудностям и может писаться как слитно(если сочтёте термином или субстантивир. прилагательным-громкоговорящий ящик = громкоговоритель) и раздельно: Громко говорящий молодой человек привлёк внимание.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Людмила!

Answer (score 1):

Для словосочетаний/сложных слов вроде «контекстно()зависимый», «контекстно()свободный», «объектно()ориентированный», «телесно()ориентированный» и т.п нету единого написания.

1. С одной стороны, русский орфографический словарь РАН (4-е издание, 2013) и, например, следующая за ним грамота.ру предлагают раздельное написание: «**контекстно зависимый**» ([Лопатин](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)), «**контекстно свободный**» ([Лопатин](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)), «**объектно ориентированный**» ([Лопатин](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)), «**телесно ориентированный**» ([грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=277774)) и т.п. <sub>Причём в некоторых случаях написание в словарях устаканилось [недавно](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=229282), т.е. создаётся впечатление, что они лишь недавно пришли к единой норме.</sub>
2. С другой стороны, профильная литература практиковала и практикует исключительно дефисное написание — по крайней мере, в составе некоторых терминов: «***контекстно-зависимая*** грамматика», «***контекстно-свободная*** грамматика», «***объектно-ориентированное*** программирование», «***телесно-ориентированная*** психотерапия» и т.п.

То, что первая часть может интерпретироваться как наречие и из двух частей можно сделать полноценное словосочетание вида ⟨наречие⟩ + ⟨причастие или прилагательное⟩», не означает, что из двух частей нельзя сделать сложное прилагательное. Например, Розенталь говорит: [«Возможно различное написание одних и тех же определений в зависимости от их понимания. Ср.: [...].»](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49) (в конце страницы). Проект «Орфографический конкорданс» пишет более подходящую к нашей ситуации вещь: [«Вводятся также дополнительные критерии для отдельных слов: термин/нетермин, наличие/отсутствие намерения подчеркнуть цельность выражаемого признака.»](http://lexrus.ru/sprav.aspx?p=3133&par=51). То же мы находим в «Объяснительном русском орфографическом словаре-справочнике» Е. Бешенковой, О. Ивановой и Л. Чельцовой: «как исключение пишется через дефис [...] — при намерении подчеркнуть цельность выражаемого признака (в т. ч. в терминах), напр.: объёмно-центрированный (кристаллическая решётка), объёмно-детонирующий (взрыв)».

### Вывод

Если Вы используете термин, который пишется именно через дефис (и уверены, что используете слова в том же смысле, в котором они используются в качестве термина) или хотите особо подчеркнуть цельность выражаемого признака (объединение в одно слово придаёт дополнительный смысл, например, объектно-ориентированное программирование — это не просто программирование, ориентированное на объекты, это отдельная парадигма) — смело пишите через дефис. Если же это не общепринятый термин и особого оттенка смысла ему придавать не нужно — лучше пишите раздельно.

В Вашем случае я бы писал раздельно. Т.к. Вы просто переводите с английского словосочетание «context sensitive», что судя по всему означает просто «зависящий от контекста» (и даже в оригинале написано раздельно, хотя это не всегда аргумент). Даже если Вы опосля узнаете, что это таки был специальный термин — это не так страшно, т.к. Вы в переводе использовали словосочетание с более широкой областью применения, чем можно было, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Пишется через дефис. См. правила:

[wikiznanie.ru](http://www.wikiznanie.ru/wikipedia/index.php/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81,_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

В данном случае действует Примечание 1 к §81:

> Примечание 1. Прилагательные, образованные из двух или более основ, не
>   подходящие под перечисленные правила, пишутся через дефис, например:
>   литературно-художественный (альманах), политико-массовая (работа),
>   словарно-технический (отдел), подзолисто-болотный,
>   рыхло-комковато-пылеватый, удлинённо-ланцетовидный.

И там же кстати говорится:

> Примечание. Сложные прилагательные, в состав которых входят наречия,
>   не следует смешивать со словосочетаниями, состоящими из наречия и
>   прилагательного (или причастия) и пишущимися раздельно, например:
>   диаметрально противоположный, прямо противоположный, чисто русский,
>   детски наивный, плохо скрываемый, отчётливо выраженный.

Пологаю, что в указанном случае всё-таки сложное прилагательное, потому и дефис.

Если к Викизнаниям нет доверия, можно заглянуть в свод правил из А. Бисеров "ЕГЭ 2014. Русский язык. ГИА. ЕГЭ. Нормы оценки знаний" страницы [221-222](https://books.google.fi/books?id=zLiCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%22%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%22&source=bl&ots=e7K6iL0JPC&sig=KEyS6Y0Vuc7-p2WPTnI6e0bSs14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN8NLTtvDJAhUB_HIKHXxhCekQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%22&f=false).

Кое-какие комментарии также в связи с проектом изменений свода правил [здесь](http://www.tetran.ru/SiteContent/Details/85), но и тут словоупотребление идёт для нашего случая в сторону написаний с дефисом, даже если раньше могло считаться исключением.

Вообще говоря, написание может зависеть от "намерения подчеркнуть цельность выражаемого признака (в т. ч. в терминах)". Так что правильное написание зависит от контекста. (см. [обсуждение на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9A_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/22_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F_2015#.D0.9F.D0.BE_.D0.B2.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BC))

Приведу цитату из статьи Кауновой «Проблема разграничения сложных прилагательных и словосочетаний в практике письма»: "На наш взгляд, сочетания „наречие + причастие/прилагательное“ не должны и не могут быть строго орфографически регламентированы, так как в лингвистике отсутствуют четкие критерии разграничения слова и словосочетания. Проблема оформления этих единиц в русском языке остается неразрешенной и актуальной в наши дни.»